# what is the diffrence between a term , constant and variable in first order logic languages ?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

in the text , the author says that the language contains parenthises , sentintial connectives and n-place functions , n-place predicates , equality sign = , terms , constans and variables

i have two question ,

1- what is the definition of a term , constant and variable ?! 
and what is the diffrence between them ?

2- what is the definition of n-place predicate ?

thanx !

Comment: It is very nice of Hagen von Eitzen and Berci to respond. But I'd say it was quite inappropriate to ask here for explanations of absolutely basic terminology that any good text book will explain. If you don't understand one text, make the effort to get another book or two out of library and read *their* explanations.

Comment: @PeterSmith , u r right but if you live in a village in egypt then the idea of getting one or two books to ckeck the definition is not practical! because  this may require a long time to get this text !

Comment: Fair enough -- but there are good texts freely and legally availably online (Google for Paul Teller, *Modern Logic Primer*, for example).

Comment: i will :) i use enderton's text . i will search for those online free texts :) thanx professor

Comment: No , @PeterSmith is not right, because ANY of the questions people ask on this site can be found by sufficiently studying "any good text book" but apart from the fact that a "good text book" is not always easy to find. Different people understand a topic quicker and more easily than other people. So why spend days or weeks struggling to understand something that may or may not be trivial, when you could simply ask a question and then move on to tackling more pressing problems. ALL of my text books give the terms asked about in this post and NONE define them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constant is a symbol. A variable is also a symbol. The difference comes from how they can be used (syntactically). For example, a symbol $v$ can occur with a quantor (as in $\forall v$) only if $v$ is a vraiable, not if it is a constant.
Terms are words (symbol sequences) in the language, again obeying certain rules; for example constants and variables are the simplest terms and new terms are obtained from simpler terms by connectives.
As a matter of fact, the details of these distinctions should be apparent with what I assume the author writes in the nest few paragraphs after these remarks.

Answer (score 3):

A variable is a symbol like $x$ standing for a variable, so these are the basic bricks. *Terms* are built up from variables and operation symbols, recursively:

- Each variable itself is also a term,
- and whenever $\tau_1,..,\tau_n$ are terms, and $f$ is an $n$-ary operation symbol ($n$ place function, as you called), then the string $f(\tau_1,..,\tau_n)$ is again a term.

A *constant* is basically a *nullary operation*, i.e. it inputs $0$ pieces of elements and outputs one element, so in practice, a constant will be a particular element in any structure ('incarnation') of the given language. Constants themselves are also terms.

An $n$-ary predicate symbol $R$ is then realized in an $n$-ary relation in the structrues. If $a_1,..,a_n$ are concrete elements in a concrete structure, then $R(a_1,..,a_n)$ is either true or false.

For example consider the language with one binary operation symbol $+$ and one binary relation symbol $\le$ and a constant $0$. A *structure* of this is e.g. $\Bbb N$ (or $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$) with the usual interpretations of these symbols. A quantifier-free formula is for example
$$(x+y)+x\le 0$$